# Add 2-3 images in the mouse hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this code for mouse hover zoom effect and it is working without error. But I want to add 2-3 images so as the user clicks on it, then that image is shown and mouse hover effect works on it, i.e. on hovering the mouse on the picture shows a zoom effect.

Here is my code:

```
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  
  /*initialise and hide lens result*/
  result.style.display = "none";
  /*Reveal and hide on mouseover or out*/
  lens.onmouseover = function(){result.style.display = "block";};
  lens.onmouseout = function(){result.style.display = "none";};
  
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
};

imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px; /*match width of #myimage*/
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result" style=""></div>
</div>

<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>
```

I was searching for the answer and hope here i will get the solution.

Thank  you in advance.

Comment: Why not just copy paste the html of image and result, renaming id like `myresult2` and `myresult2` and using `imageZoom("myimage2", "myresult2");`

Comment: bro this will make all the images to be visible directly. I want to use this hover effect only on the selected image by the user... Like user selects the image and that image open ups.....

Answer (score 0):

Just add more picture like this:

```
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result" style=""></div>
</div>


<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage2" src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult2" class="img-zoom-result" style=""></div>
</div>



<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage3" src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult3" class="img-zoom-result" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Then add more calling function

```
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage2", "myresult2");
imageZoom("myimage3", "myresult3");
```

;)

Comment: in this all the images will be shown directly. Let me give you an example. Like you might have seen amazon page?  There you could see 5-6 images on the left side and when you click on it then that image open ups and then only on that picture mouse hover effect works. I want to make something like that. Thank you

Comment: Then just add smaller image on your left then add onclick event to change the image like
`onclick="document.getElementByID('myimage').src = 'https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions2.jpg'; "`

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

img:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
```

no need for JS to have a hover effect on an image. You can do that purely with CSS by adding `:hover` to its class/id.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion bro. But i just need to add 2-3 images as i have told abve.

Comment: thats the thing, your approach to write complicated JS for it is wrong. Simply set a :hover to the images and you can have as many Images as you want works for all without JS.

Comment: actually bro i am using this in a website that i am designing. And using this makes other things like written sentences get shifted from there place which is disturbing the whole page. And it would very difficult to change everything. Thats why i am trying to fix it with the same code. Thank a lot for your suggestion and help.